# ExtJS filter() on store for exact match

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1. I have a store which is having a model. Model contains three fields ID, Name, age. This store is attached to a grid.

This is how the data looks:

[image]

I user filter function on the store to apply filter.

So when i apply filter on Id 'Manu', i see two results in grid
 myStore.filter('ID', 'Manu'); //Works fine

**Problem**
myStore.filter('ID', 'Sales'); //
retuns 4 results. It also includes result for ID 'Sales One' and 'Sales Two'

**What I Want:** When I filter on 'Sales' ID, it should return only results for ID 'Sales'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myStore.filter([
   {filterFn: function(item) { return item.get('ID') == 'Sales'; }}
]);
```